# Toggle Height/.Top Constriants of NSTableView by pressing a button

Tags: swift, nstableview, nslayoutconstraint

so i have a NSTableView that presents information, then i have an add button that shows a view that is hidden behind the tables view. It is shown by changing the tableview's height to lower and setting its hidden property to false. I am running into the problem where i have constraints set in storyboard for the tableview and when i try change its frame programatically the storyboard constraints overrule the frame i set in code. What i need is for the constraints to be:

When the tableview is at full size:

- Left: 200
- Right: 0
- Bottom: 20
- Top: 20

When the tableview is shrunken to show the view below:

- Left: 200
- Right: 0
- Bottom: 20
- Top: 110

I want to use constraints because when people resize the window the table view should scale.

Basically i need to be able to toggle the height constraint (or the .Top constraint) the rest should stay the same.